# tricky hibernate criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have a sql statement which I want to move it into hibernate criteria, but I am not clue how to do this.

The problem is one of the WHERE clause which looks like the following

***...(skip other parts)...  ? ILIKE strprefix||'%' ...(continue)***

strprefix is the column name, the ? is the place i need to fill in the value.

With criteria, I can use

***criteria.add(Expression.ilike(propertyName, value));***

but in this case, how can i do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can likely handle this with `Restrictions.sqlRestriction(String sql)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in `Criteria`, columns are set since they represent the properties in your domain object. You need to query against the property not the other way around.

Comment: The closest you can get is `.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("propertyName","otherPropertyName")` which will not do what you want